# array_push doesn't insert value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This is the example code:

```
//$pieces is an stdClass object which has 4 elements the foreach loops through
$arr = array();
foreach($pieces as $piece)
{
     $piece->value = 1;
     array_push($arr, $piece);

     $piece->value = 3;
     array_push($arr, $piece);
}
```

The problem with that is it doesn't use the first `array_push`, just like it wasnt there, in the results I got:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
             [piece] = 3
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
             [piece] = 3
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
             [piece] = 3
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
             [piece] = 3
        )
)
```

While there should be additional 4 keys with the `[piece] = 1`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Tip: Have you considered using `$array[] = $value` vs `array_push` for single items?

Comment: @Marty Sure, results are the same.

Comment: Of course, it's just nicer to read, faster to type and even more efficient (on a tiny scale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to clone the `$piece` object, your code currently saves references to `$piece` into `$arr`. This snippet assumes you need actual copies for both `$piece` variants in your array.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($pieces as $piece)
{
     $first_clone = clone $piece;
     $first_clone->value = 1;
     array_push($arr, $first_clone);

     $second_clone = clone $piece;
     $second_clone->value = 3;
     array_push($arr, $second_clone);
}
```

Comment: I guess the second clone is not needed?

Comment: Depends on your use case. If you need all the objects in `$arr` to be independent from `$pieces` you need both clones.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are always references. You would need to `clone` the object before trying to use it as if it were two different things.